# SQL putting select in case

Tags: sql, select

I have 3 tables Emp, Payroll_Emp, and tbCompany
there's no relation between Emp and tbCompany

i did that query but im getting for all the employees the same CeilingEOS
i need to sum for each employee the ceilingEOS
i know that i have to put SUM(CeilingEOS) in the select but it's not working too
can someone help me please

```
DECLARE @CeilingEOS decimal(18,2)

SET  @CeilingEOS=(select SUM (CeilingEOS)  FROM Payroll_Emp inner join emp on Payroll_Emp.Employee_Id = Emp.[ID] where @Date>=Payroll_Emp.Payroll_From)

select Emp.ID, tbCompany.ID, tbCompany.CompanyName, tbCompany.CEmpRepDesc, 
Emp.SSN, 

--case  when Payroll_Emp.CeilingEOS IS NOT NULL then select SUM(CeilingEOS) as ceilingEOS
from Payroll_Emp where Payroll_Emp.Employee_Id = Emp.[ID] group by Emp.ID end


FROM  tbCompany, Emp -- inner join Payroll_Emp on Payroll_Emp.Employee_Id = Emp.[ID]  
where @Date >= Emp.HireSince and Emp.ID=Emp.[ID]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this :

```
DECLARE 
    @CompanyID uniqueidentifier, 
    @CompanyName nvarchar(max), 
    @CEmpRepDesc nvarchar(max)

select top 1 @CompanyID = tbCompany.ID, @CompanyName= tbCompany.CompanyName, @CEmpRepDesc = tbCompany.CEmpRepDesc from tbCompany

select Emp.ID, Emp.SSN, ComputedInfos.CeilingEOS, @CompanyID, @CompanyName, @CEmpRepDesc
from Emp 
left join (select Emp.ID as EmpID, SUM(CeilingEOS) as CeilingEOS from Emp join Payroll_Emp on Payroll_Emp.Employee_Id = Emp.[ID] where @Date >= Emp.HireSince group by Emp.ID) ComputedInfos 
    on ComputedInfos.EmpID = Emp.ID
where @Date >= Emp.HireSince
```

Comment: I don't have a relation between the table Emp and tbCompany.
And the group by!! I think there's something more powerful to use instead of writing all the fields.. There's a lot of people that uses what you just wrote but i think it's wrong

Comment: How do you determine the employee's company ?

Comment: there's only one company, all the employees belong to that company

Comment: Ok ! That's working ... Thank You so much.. that's so advanced!!
I really appreciate your help

Comment: I must add a question here.. If I had more than one company, i can use tbMultiCompany where there's relation between the Emp and tbMultiCompany..
the same method can be used ? the select top 1 ... ?
Sorry for bothering you again

Comment: You can add 

    "... from Emp
    join tbMultiCompany on Emp.CompanyID = tbMultiCompany.ID
    left join ..."